# Windows Terminal emulator can't connect to the Internet

Tags: windows

I am trying to get a Windows Terminal emulator to work with Windows 7, 64-bit.  I have tried Console2 and ConEmu.  At the command prompt I can ping my local xampp or EasyPHP server but I can't ping google.com or any Internet sites.  I have extension=php_openssl.dll enabled in php.ini
Any ideas? If you need more information please ask.
======== edited below for Maximus =====
When I have ConEmu open and at the command line I type:  ping 127.0.0.1  I get replies, when I type: ping google.com I get "Ping request could not find host google.com"

Comment: Why do you talking about Console2 or ConEmu? They do not relate to your question at all. And the question is not properly written.

Comment: Maximus, you are the author of ConEmu, please tell me what do you not understand about the question?

Comment: The question is about setting up networking on Windows, and is off-topic. Perhaps [server-fault](http://serverfault.com/), although this is an elementary question.